# How to Specify NoShipping 1 with Express Checkout checkout.js v4

Tags: paypal

I have express checkout working with the latest checkout.js but do not need to show any shipping address.  Since it's a digital good, the docs say I need noshipping set to 1.  However, I can't figure out how that goes into the javascript.

I followed the [basic integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/) steps and then used the REST API to execute the payment so I can charge to my server.

I've tried adding noshipping:1 all over the place within the javascript to create the payment with no luck.  Here's what it looks like ( ignore compile issues as I'm just trying to show how I tried adding the noshipping:1 information):

```
 payment: function() {
            var env    = this.props.env;
            var client = this.props.client;
            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '4.99', currency: 'USD' }
                        DOESNT WORK-->noshipping: 1
                    }
                ],
                DOESNT WORK-->noshipping: 1
            });
        },
```

Does anyone know how to properly pass the noshipping information using the latest checkout.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, it appears that they have finally added support for this.  It looks like this:

```
                payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '19.99', currency: 'USD' }
                        // Possibly there is also a 'custom' field we can specify here;
                        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320753/
                    }
                ],
                application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's June 2018 and the documentation still says "shipping_preferences" (with an "s") but you are correct that it is "shipping_preference" based on what I'm seeing when I try it. And it appears to work.

Comment: That drove me insane! It's singular and not plural! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Got an "official" response from paypal support a week later:

> Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Services.
>
> Unfortunately we do not have an option for the noshipping when using
>   REST API. That option is only available on the classic express
>   checkout which uses the NVP/SOAP API.

There it is.  This fairly simple concept isn't possible with their latest SDK.

Comment: Unrelated but might also help others questioning the usefulness of the REST API. I was also trying to use it for a cart type solution to take payments on behalf of other accounts and have an official PayPal response: "Unfortunately the option to do REST API on behalf of an account is not available at this moment. You would need to use the NVP classic API for this option." This is 2017, and I've seen comments from PayPal in 2013 saying that it's 'coming soon'!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way to specify NOSHIPPING as follows on PayPal-Python-SDK, as per your code:

```
 payment: function() {
        var env    = this.props.env;
        var client = this.props.client;
        return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '4.99', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ],
           application_context: {
                shipping_preferences: 'NO_SHIPPING',
            }
        });
    },
```

I hope it helps.