# PayPal Express Checkout pass transactionID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

Im Implementing PayPal's Client Side REST implementation for Express Checkout:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/client-side-REST-integration/

How does anyone know what the field is where you pass them a transaction or reference ID that they will then return via the?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

Tried transaction.reference_id, and the invoice_number fields. No luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50673345/2151420

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is wondering you can make use of the 'custom' parameter bound to each transaction object.